# Proving q is prime in the Legendre Symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $p$ is an odd prime and if $q$ is the least integer such that  $0$ < $q$ < $p$ and $\left(\frac qp\right)= -1 $, then q is prime.

I've tried to solve it by contradiction. I assumed that $q$ was a composite and then stated that $q$= $a$ $b$ where $a$ and $b$ are primes and that $$\left(\frac qp\right)= \left(\frac ap\right)\left(\frac bp\right)=-1 $$. So either $\left(\frac ap\right)$ is -1 or $\left(\frac bp\right)$ is -1. I don't know what to do from here onwards and am not sure what I've done so far is correct. A hint in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously $a$ and $b$ are $< q$ and you have a contradiction to the assumption that q is the smallest integer with $\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)= -1 $.

Comment: You have the basic idea, if $q$ is not prime, then $q=ab$ for some $1 \lt a,b \lt q$.  However we cannot say that both $a,b$ are prime in this setting (we can assert that one of them is, if that helps).

Comment: @gammatester that's true but is that enough to prove this? Or should I use direct proof? I couldn't figure it out through the direct way so I used this instead.

Comment: @hardmath we can however say that $q$ is a multiple of several primes right? And if $q$ is reducible then it's not the least integer and hence the proof is correct by contradiction?

Comment: I can see only one missing part in the proof: You cannot assume that $q=ab$
with two primes $a,b$. But if $q$ is composite, its factorization has at least
one prime factor $a$  with $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = -1$. And this $a$ gives
the contradiction.

Comment: But if we assume that $q$ is a product of multiple primes, then will that be enough to prove this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rule out that $q=1$, so that $q \gt 1$.

Then proceed by assuming $q=ab$ unless $q$ is prime, with $1 \lt a,b \lt q \lt p$.

Use the fact that the [Legendre symbol is a completely multiplicative function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Properties_of_the_Legendre_symbol):

$$ \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) \left( \frac{b}{p} \right) = \left( \frac{q}{p} \right) = -1
$$

Now you can use the assumption that $q$ is the least residue mod $p$ which gives a Legendre symbol value of -1 to get a contradiction.  Hence $q$ must be prime.